# Batch file to check if another batch is open and do something when it gets closed

Tags: batch-file

I’m trying to get a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) my other program can call upon, so that when my other program is closed it deletes a temp file the other program created, the program runs a loop so I can’t just put it before an exit command within the program as it would never get to it.

```
@echo off  
Title watcher  
:start  
//if other .bat file is open then  
goto start  
Else //then when it is closed  
Del file.txt  
Exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Does something like

```
@ECHO OFF
START "" /WAIT "C:\Program Files\Foo\OtherApplication.exe"
DEL "C:\Temp\Foo.tmp"
```

not work?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who can't use Christoph's answer, there is an incredibly slow work-around.

```
@echo off

:loop
set "l=0"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('tasklist /v') do (
    for /f %%j in ('echo %%i ^| find /c "process name"') do (
        set /a l+=%%j
        goto break
    )
)
:break
cls
if %l% gtr 0 (
    echo Process is still running...
) else (
    echo Process is not running
)
goto loop
```

You can change the process name of your batch file with `title`, or just search for the file path.